# QR Code - Can it call an API to update a database record?

Tags: database, qr-code

Can a QR code call an API that could insert or update a database record (as long as it is under the 3k data limit)?

I am writing a database, and hoping to be able to do some things with QR codes. I'm wondering what it technically possible, because if it isn't then this won't work at all.

Comment: QR codes are dead images that cant do anything by themselves. However an app scanning those codes can do whatever it pleases. In other words QR code serves as Identity for specific task, action or object.

Comment: So, as long as the API call is imbedded within the image, it can do it?

Comment: The QR code can produce the API Url when scanned, yes. But to invoke the API / URL you will need an app or user will need to copy and paste it in browser

Comment: Ok, so if the scanning is done WITHIN an app, it can be directed differently than of it is just scanned by the camera, which generally just opens a URL. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: yes. When the app is designed by you, you can choose to do as you please and use the QR code as an identifier

Comment: QR codes are not "magical applications" but merely used to **represent a string in computer-readable form**. In principle nothing else than can be typed on a keyboard. You can use QR codes to represent a single use token to do things when scanned by an app or similar. But again, many other barcode symbologies (DM, PDF417, Aztec, Dotcode, ...) could do the same.